# Drag-Drop HTML, prevent images dropping inside other images

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I'm using the js-html code from w3 to implement a drag-drop functionality.

```
function allowDrop(ev)
{
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev)
{
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev)
{
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}

<img id = 'i1' src = 'image1.png' draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" alt='' />
<img id = 'i2' src = 'image2.png' draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" alt='' />

<div id = 'fill1' ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id = 'fill2' ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```

The idea is to put one image inside each div; however, when I'm trying to put both images inside one div, it puts the second image inside the first image like this:

```
<div id="fill1" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="drop(event)">
    <img id="i1" alt="" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true" src="image1.png">
        <img id="i2" alt="" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true" src="image2.png">
    </img>
</div>
```

Is it possible to block such behavior directly or, for example, by preventing dropping inside a div, which already has one child element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do so in your drop method

call `getChildrenByTagName(target,"img")`

(function added just for reference ,you dont need to define it, actually available in javascript)

```
function getChildrenByTagName(parent,tag_name) {
    var all_children = parent.childNodes;
    var new_children = new Array();
    for (var i=0, j=0; i<all_children.length; i++) {
        if (all_children[i].tagName && (all_children[i].tagName.toLowerCase() == tag_name.toLowerCase())) {
            new_children[j] = all_children[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    return new_children;
}
```

check if this function returns a children with tag name `img`

if yes, then do not append the new child